# Display overlay on hover using only css without javascript

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a full page overlay when I hover on my navbar menu `ul`

the overlay `div` is on the top of the page

When I hover on the `ul` the `li` links appear but the overlay doesn't.
How can I make appear the overlay using CSS only can anybody help?

This is the HTML and CSS code the full code of the header whith the `span` icons, `ul` and `li`. My intention is that when I hover on the `ul` the `li` links appear like in the code below and the overlay appear now only the `li` links appear

```css
.header .container .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .container .row img {
    max-width: 207px;
    max-height: 207px;
}

.header .container .row .links {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon {
    width: 1.875em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span {
    background-color: var(--whiteColor);
    margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
    height: 0.125em;
    background-color: #000;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:first-child {
    width: 100%;

}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:nth-child(2) {

    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:last-child {
    width: 60%;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.header .container .row .links:hover .icon span:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 12.5em;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 15px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links ul::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 0.625em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    right: 0.3125em;
    top: -1.25em;
}

.header .container .row ul li {
    padding: 1em;
}

.header .container .row ul li a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: var(--whiteColor);
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}

.header .container .row ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--grayColor);
}

.header .container .row .links:hover ul,
.header .container .row .links:hover .overlay{
    display: block;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://images01.nicepage.com/51/41/51417a6d3ee82530e9117219a42fd762.png">
                <div class="links">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">catering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example as a snippet?

Comment: You cannot select ( with just CSS )  an element when hovering another element when these 2 elements don't have any relationship between them and when the second element is not after the first element . You should take a look at javascript.

Comment: Interesting how the question specifically asking for a "no javascript" solution, yet answer with javascript was accepted.

Comment: @vanowm  because the answers were that it can't be done using only css

Comment: You can't with your current html setup, but with a little modification of html it can be done. There are plenty of examples with pure CSS popups out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a little bit `Javascript` and boom it's makes your navbar so attractive.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
  font-size: 40px;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>


<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

**Explation of `JS` used**:

`onclick()`  is used here to call the function **openNav** by default set it's `display:none;` and then make `display:block` when someone calling `openNav()` fucntion.

Let me know if this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you cannot change `parent` element on `child` hover using pure `CSS` you have to use use `javascript` to achieve it...

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript for this purpose, unfortunately, as far as I know. I have created an inner overlay div and two JS events to cope with the situation.

```js
document.querySelector(".links").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    let overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    let overlayContent = overlay.querySelector(".overlay-content");
    overlayContent.style.width = document.body.clientWidth + "px";
    overlayContent.style.height = document.body.clientHeight + "px";
});

document.querySelector(".links").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    let overlay = document.querySelector(".overlay");
    overlay.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
.header .container .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .container .row img {
    max-width: 207px;
    max-height: 207px;
}

.header .container .row .links {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon {
    width: 1.875em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span {
    background-color: var(--whiteColor);
    margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
    height: 0.125em;
    background-color: #000;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:first-child {
    width: 100%;

}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:nth-child(2) {

    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:last-child {
    width: 60%;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.header .container .row .links:hover .icon span:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 12.5em;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 15px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links ul::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 0.625em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    right: 0.3125em;
    top: -1.25em;
}

.header .container .row ul li {
    padding: 1em;
}

.header .container .row ul li a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: var(--whiteColor);
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}

.header .container .row ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--grayColor);
}

.header .container .row .links:hover ul,
.header .container .row .links:hover .overlay{
    display: block;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}

.overlay-content {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
    <div class="overlay"><div class="overlay-content"></div></div>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://images01.nicepage.com/51/41/51417a6d3ee82530e9117219a42fd762.png">
                <div class="links">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">catering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to use at least a little bit of javascript for this mate. Do something like this:

```js
    let icon = document.getElementsByClassName('icon')[0];
    let offCanvas = document.getElementsByClassName('offCanvas')[0];
    let overlay = document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0];

    icon.onmouseenter= () => {
        overlay.style.display = "block";
        overlay.style.opacity = "0";
        overlay.style.animation = "overlay .5s forwards";
    }

    icon.onmouseleave = () => {
        overlay.style.animation = "overlayHide .5s forwards";
    }
```

```css
.header .container .row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.header .container .row img {
    max-width: 207px;
    max-height: 207px;
}

.header .container .row .links {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon {
    width: 1.875em;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span {
    background-color: var(--whiteColor);
    margin-bottom: 0.3125em;
    height: 0.125em;
    background-color: #000;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:first-child {
    width: 100%;

}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:nth-child(2) {

    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links .icon span:last-child {
    width: 60%;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.header .container .row .links:hover .icon span:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}

.header .container .row .links ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 12.5em;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(100% + 15px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.header .container .row .links ul::before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 0.625em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #000 transparent;
    right: 0.3125em;
    top: -1.25em;
}

.header .container .row ul li {
    padding: 1em;
}

.header .container .row ul li a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: var(--whiteColor);
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
}

.header .container .row ul li a:hover {
    color: var(--grayColor);
}

.header .container .row .links:hover ul,
.header .container .row .links:hover .overlay{
    display: block;
}

.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 0.8em;
    padding-left: 0.8em;
}

.icon {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}

@keyframes overlay {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes overlayHide {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
  <div class="overlay"></div>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <img src="https://images01.nicepage.com/51/41/51417a6d3ee82530e9117219a42fd762.png">
                <div class="links">
                    <span class="icon">
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </span>
                    <div class="offCanvas">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">catering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```