# Without JavaScript, meaning CSS only. How can I create this element given to me in a mockup

Tags: html, css

For my boot camp assignment, I have to create a website from a mockup. Because this isn't a real-life scenario I am unable to use javascript.

In the mockup. there is this animation.

[image: Mock up of Element]

I was able to successfully recreate the layout. Below is a simplified version with a grey background.

```css
.menu-item {
  background: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item-title-container {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.item-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.item-desc-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<li class="menu-item">
          <div class="item-title-container">
            <p class="item-title">Grandmother's Vegetable Soup</p>
          </div>
          <div class="item-desc-container">
            <p class="item-desc">Carrots, parsnips, Jerusalem artichoke</p>
            <p class="item-price">35€</p>
          </div>
        </li>
```

I need help recreating this animation I have tried to shrink the background on hover to show the checkbox container, but I am struggling to keep the element looking organized as it does in the gif as the entire element shrinks.

I found a similar question, [Display overlay on hover using only css without javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68964151/display-overlay-on-hover-using-only-css-without-javascript).

But the answer suggests using javascript so it doesn't help.

Comment: Haven't downvoted - but here's a suggestion: Try looking into [css animations with keyframes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) - they should be sufficient here on hover, maybe some svg for the checker but thats about it - no need for js here..

Comment: Could you link me a place start?

Comment: `onMouseOver` is JS - `:hover` selector would be the CSS way.

Comment: @QuentinGibson added the link to the comment.. Just play around a bit in a stackblitz or codepen - you'll get the hang of it in no time..

Comment: I've read the page you linked before asking this question but I just don't understand how to apply it to my use case.

Comment: Looks like i had answered such a question a year ago : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyXExOd i could not find the related topic here or elsewhere. **no js involved**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a `transition` here, on `max-width`.

```css
.menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item-title-container {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.item-title {
  margin: 0;
}

.item-desc-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-price {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-item:hover .item-price {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <div class="item-title-container">
      <p class="item-title">Grandmother's Vegetable Soup</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item-desc-container">
      <p class="item-desc">Carrots, parsnips, Jerusalem artichoke</p>
      <p class="item-price">35€</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```